# How to find each next element with specific class name using jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a html structure in my webpage as below :

```
<div class="group_name">Group A</div>
<div class="student_name">Studen 1</div>
<div class="student_name">Studen 2</div>
<div class="student_name">Studen 3</div>

<div class="group_name">Group B</div>
<div class="student_name">Studen 1</div>
<div class="student_name">Studen 2</div>
<div class="student_name">Studen 3</div>

..
.
.
```

Now this structure is dynamically generated using PHP. What I want to do is, I want to add below code as a last element of "Group A" :

```
<div class="student_name">Studen 4</div>
```

But I want to add it using jQuery, as I am getting this "Student 4" record as a Ajax response string. So the div is getting added based on the Group Name. At the moment I have used static value for group name as "Group A". So the Javascript will be something like below :

```
$(".group_name").each(function(index){
    var group_name = $(this).text();

    if(group_name=='Group A'){
          // Add Student 4 to last position of this group
    }
});
```

So this way I am already selecting the "Group A" element. But now I want to add "Student 4" as the last entry in that group (below "Student 3").
How can I do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason your group `<div>` does not contain the student divs?  That would have made `.append()`ing new items trivial

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.group_name').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == 'Group A';
}).nextUntil('.group_name').filter('.student_name').last().after('<div class="student_name">Student X</div>');
```

What this code does:

- `$('.group_name')` select all groups
- `.filter(...)` reduces it to the element with the correct group name. I did not use `:contains()` as that would perform a substring match instead of an exact match.
- `.nextUntil('.group_name')` takes all following siblings which are not a new group
- `.filter('.student_name')` removes all elements that are not student elements - just in case your DOM structure is bad enough to make this necessary
- `.last()` reduces it to the last one - the place after which the new one should be inserted
- `.after(...)` inserts the new entry after that element.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/5UHgC/

---

Please note that you could make  this much easier, cleaner and more structured by changing your structure like this:

```
<div class="group" id="group-1">
    <div class="group_name">...</div>
    <div class="students">
        <div class="student_name"></div>
        <div class="student_name"></div>
        <div class="student_name"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="group" id="group-2">
    <div class="group_name">...</div>
    <div class="students">
        <div class="student_name"></div>
        <div class="student_name"></div>
        <div class="student_name"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you could simply use this:

```
$('#group-X .students').append('<div class="student_name"></div>');
```